# Javascript: element property not re-set on navigating to a new page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension. One issue that perplexes me is the perceived stickiness of elements from querySelectorAll.

I have this code from a library, which I've placed in my content.js file. The library defines the ready() function to check if a particular element has finished loading on the page, so that some actions can be taken if it's loaded. I found out that the ready function doesn't seem to do anything if I navigate from one page to another, both of the same type (same DOM structure).

I console logged everything to trouble-shoot, so in the end I concluded that the reason that no action is taken after the element finish loading is that the `if (!element.ready)` check in the `checkSelector` function fails on the second page (and any further pages). The reason is that on the first page, the element.ready is undefined, but once I navigate to a second page, the element.ready is always true. That is frankly entirely unexpected to me, as someone new to javascript. I mean, not only is the `var element` defined in a function, I also know, via console logging, that the entire content.js file is rerun on the second page I navigate to, so that the function in which `var element` is defined is re-called every time. Also, when I consoled logged the element itself, it shows it has picked up the change in content: even though the selector is defined as the same, the selected content/data is different between the first and second page, so the element logged is also different. The only way so far to resolve that problem is to refresh the second page after I navigate to it -- that causes the `var element` to be undefined again, passing the check.

My questions: What's going on? How can I make the function go through the `fn.call(element, element);` part whenever navigating to a new page?

content.js:

```
    var listeners = [],
        doc = document,
        MutationObserver = MutationObserver || WebKitMutationObserver,
        observer;

    console.log("new listeners created");

    /*
     * Checks a selector for new matching
     * elements and invokes the callback
     * if one is found
     *
     * @param {String} selector
     * @param {Function} fn
     * @api private
     */
    function checkSelector(selector, fn) {
        //var elements = ['a', 'b'];
        var elements = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
        var i = 0,
            len = elements.length, element;
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            element = elements[i];
            // Make sure the callback isn't invoked with the
            // same element more than once
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element.ready);
            if (!element.ready) {
                element.ready = true;
                console.log("so I think this part is not called in the reload");
                // Invoke the callback with the element
                fn.call(element, element);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Check all selectors for new elements
     * following a change in the DOM
     *
     * @api private
     */
    function checkListeners(mutations) {
        //console.log("checking listeners. The length is "+listeners.length);
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            //console.log(mutation.type);
        });
        for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length, listener; i < len; i++) {
            listener = listeners[i];
            //console.log(listener.selector);
            //console.log(listener.fn);
            (function() {
            checkSelector(listener.selector, listener.fn);
            })();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Add a selector to watch for when a matching
     * element becomes available in the DOM
     *
     * @param {String} selector
     * @param {Function} fn
     * @api public
     */
    function ready(selector, fn) {
        // Store the selector and callback to be monitored
        listeners.push({
            selector: selector,
            fn: fn
        });

        if (!observer) {
            observer.observe(doc.documentElement, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
                //characterData: true,
                //attributes: true
            });
        }
        // Check if the element is currently in the DOM
        checkSelector(selector, fn);

    }


ready('.pv-top-card-section__name', function (element) {
    console.log("the top card is loaded");
    headlines['full-name'] = $('.pv-top-card-section__name').text().replace(/ /g, '_').trim();
    //console.log(headlines['full-name']);
    headlines['headline'] = $('.pv-top-card-section__headline').text().trim();
    //console.log(headlines['headline']);
    headlines['company'] = $('.pv-top-card-section__company').text().trim();
    //console.log(headlines['company']);
    headlines['location'] = $('.pv-top-card-section__location').text().trim();
    //console.log(headlines['location']);
    headlines['school'] = $('.pv-top-card-section__school').text().trim();
    //console.log(headlines['school']);

});
```

Extra info:

background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function() {
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"extensions/ready.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"content.js"});
});

chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#a442f4', tabId: 1 });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'hello'});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender) {
        // read `newIconPath` from request and read `tab.id` from sender
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({

            text: request.text
        });
    });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "cloud.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background":
  {
    "scripts":["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://www.linkedin.com/in/*",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.linkedin.com/in/*"
      ],
      "js": ["extensions/jquery-2.2.2.min.js", "content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The content script environment is destroyed/created on navigating to a new page. Are you sure that what you state as "navigate" is actually going to a new URL, not just the website updating the URL without *actually* going to a new page? Multiple sites are designed to do exactly that. Along with a complete [MCVE], please be sure to tell us on which URL/site you are testing this.

Comment: @makyen It is true that the new URL likely isn't a new page, but then that's why I use this in my background.js: `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function() {
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"extensions/ready.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"content.js"});
});` When I navigate to a new page, according to my console logging, the content.js is in fact rerun, so the code I have in my question, placed in content.js, is also rerun.

Comment: I've also added more info

Comment: The posted code doesn't ring a bell. Well, except that it's terribly inefficient due to the superslow querySelectorAll on the entire document. Also, you may want to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated which detects direct hash modifications of urls unlike webNavigation

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm. What do you suggest in place of querySelectorAll? I aim to run the function defined in ready() whenever that element is loaded.

Comment: It depends on the page complexity. See [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](//stackoverflow.com/a/39332340)